# Customize the out of the box Ribbon via code

Tags: c#, vsto, visio

I am developing Visio COM Add-In.
I need to hide or disable some of the existing out-of-the-box Ribbon items (and replace them by custom functionality).
I see the option to "Import/Export" Ribbon options but didn't find a way to this at runtime.
Can anyone provide the class OR method to grab the OOTB Ribbon and manipulate it?

Thanks

Comment: I wrote a post about that a few years ago, summarizing my findings, maybe you will find it interesting http://unmanagedvisio.com/disabling-visio-built-in-commands/#targetText=Basically%20it%20works%20as%20following,and%20enter%20the%20command%20id.

Comment: Hi Nikolay & thanks for your response. I've tried few ways but couldn't make it through code. I need to disable the builtin Layers buttons. Importing CustomUI isn't working from Code & I also tried MenuSets & BuiltInToolbars didn't provide any access to Layers...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved:
I've loaded my custom menu using the following code:

```
internal void SetRibbonCustomUI()
{
    string customUI = = @"<customUI onLoad=""_MyRibbon.Load"" xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"">";
    customUI += @"<ribbon>";
    customUI += @"<tabs>";
    customUI += @"<tab idMso=""TabHome"">";
    customUI += @"<group idMso=""GroupEditing"" visible=""false""/>";
    customUI += @"</tab>";
    customUI += @"</tabs>";
    customUI += @"</ribbon>";
    customUI += @"</customUI>";

    this.Application.ActiveDocument.CustomUI = customUI;
}
```

The key issue in this solution was the use of method: `_MyRibbon.Load`
Whenever this event occurs the customized menu will be loaded.
The only problem is that the menu is loaded before the document, so, you need to save & reopen your document in order to see the customization... ;)